# Does Fallout 3 (XBox Classics/Platinum Hits) contain the 5 DLC packs like the GOTY edition?

Tags: fallout-3

I have been looking all over the web to find out if the Xbox Classics/Platinum Hits version of the game (the one with the extra green border on the cover art) has the DLC content from the GOTY edition included.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'Classics/Platinum Hits' version does not contain any DLC content. Only the GOTY edition includes the extra content.

[Platinum Hits Version](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Fallout+3+Platinum+Hits+-+Xbox+360/8813313.p?skuId=8813313&ci_src=14110944&ci_sku=8813313&ref=06&loc=01&id=1206749191125)

[Game of the Year Version](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Fallout+3%3A+Game+of+the+Year+Edition+-+Xbox+360/9554207.p?skuId=9554207&IcsCsid=2-39-1003-25-5-1076-36565-25-1003-849-25-1003-3930-0-1&id=1218123464451)